# Registering custom protocol in Electron to accept post requests?

Tags: electron

Is it possible to register [custom protocol](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol) in Electron, for example `md-file://upload` that when my component in view will send a `POST` `request` I will able to handle it, get `request.body` object, process it, and return the HTTP response object?

For example I registering my custom protocol as following:

```js
  protocol.registerStringProtocol("md-file", function (request, callback){
    console.log("md-file", request);
    callback({
       data: '1231231'
    });
  })
```

It works but I don't see any `body` or `Form Data` in the `request` object, and I can't find in the documentation do I suppose to get those objects and I'm doing something wrong or it's the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Get an answer from one of the Electron's developers here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17531#issuecomment-700952791

This is a fundamental limitation of `XMLHttpRequest`: it only sends upload bodies to Http/Https. (see here for the definition of ProtocolIsInHTTPFamily.)

fetch() does not have this problem if you register your protocol as supporting Fetch. I've modified your example to show how: https://gist.github.com/e8f8f2322c5452d941a4fcc05f063942